# Para que serve o método clipboardData.getData()?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber sobre o que exatamente este código faz.

```
let text = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
```

Estou usando este método para a função de colar pelo <kbd>ctrl-v</kbd>. O projeto em si é uma calculadora e esse código faz com que eu cole um número copiado de outro lugar e fique exatamente no display da minha calculadora, melhorando a interatividade do usuário.

Meu código abaixo:

```
pasteFromClipboard() {                                                                             
    document.addEventListener('paste', e => {
        let text = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        this.displayCalc = parseFloat(text);    
    });
}
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas sobre esse método e não achei muita coisa. Agradeço por qualquer informação que consigam me dar sobre ele.

Comment: Quando dizes _"esse código faz com que eu cole um número copiado de outro lugar"_ já explicas o que esse código faz... qual é a dúvida que te resta?

Comment: Achei q existisse uma definição maior ou que fosse usado de outras formas procurei em vários forúns e não achei muita coisa sobre ele não...

Answer (score 3):

Olha só, tem algumas coisas que você precisa entender:
Event é o evento que vc está recebendo na sua arrow func... 
Basicamente, nele contém todos os dados de um determinado evento do usuário...

Você pode dar um console.log(e) pra vc entender o que vc recebe nesse evento específico.

A segunda coisa que vc precisa entender é o addEventListener, que adiciona um "ouvidor" pra um determinado evento... No caso, vc está ouvindo o "paste", que é quando o usuário faz ctrl v... Nesse evento específico, ele possui um elemento no evento que é o clipboardData, onde vc pode fazer diversas coisas, uma dela é o getData...

No javascript tudo é um objeto... você pode dar um console.log em determinados objetos pra entendê-los melhor, como por exemplo:

```
pasteFromClipboard() {
    document.addEventListener('paste', e => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log(e.clipboardData);
        let text = e.clipboardData.getData('Text');
        this.displayCalc = parseFloat(text);
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com o [artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) no site da MDN, o método `DataTransfer.getData()` serve para obter o conteúdo colado na área de transferência. Isso significa que no seu código, este método irá devolver o texto que você colou no seu documento.

Veja o exemplo abaixo para que possa entender melhor:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("inputField");

input.onpaste = (event) => {
    const div = document.getElementById("display");
    div.innerText = "Você colou o texto: " + event.clipboardData.getData("text");
}
```

```html
<input id="inputField" placeholder="Cole um texto aqui"/>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Li recentemente afirmações dizendo:

> como sabem não dá pra copiar ou colar nada em cima de um SVG ... e.clipboardData.getData('Text'), então este método conseguiu conseguiu colar algo em SVG

Sobre esta citação quero ressaltar alguns problemas de entendimento:

- `ClipboardData.getData()` existe desde o Internet Explorer 5.5, navegador lançado em 2000
- SVG passou a ser suportado somente no Internet Explorer 9, navegador lançado em 2011
- IE5.5 e IE9 tem 11 anos de diferença e o método `ClipboardData.getData()` já existia antes do suporte ao SVG.

Então não tem porque o `getData` ser uma vantagem para o **SVG**, a real "vantagem" é aplicar o que está no *clipboard* do usuário para uma ação **customizada** conforme a necessidade do projeto/aplicação.

O uso dentro do evento `paste` é um mero exemplo apenas, mas poderia ser usado de outra forma e em outros eventos (como `copy`, citei um exemplo perto do final da resposta).

Não é que não dá pra colar nada no **SVG**, simplesmente não dá pra colar em lugar algum que **NÃO FOR**:

- `INPUT`
- `TEXTAREA`
- E que não possua o atributo `contentEditable` (ou documento com `designmode`, popularmente chamado de "richtext")

Ou seja, nem mesmo colar em um **DIV** você conseguirá.

Com `ClipboardData.getData()` é possível obter o clipboard do usuário em um momento oportuno de maneira que você possa customizar a ação, assim como editar um DIV ou SVG em tempo de execução para que ele apresente o valor que estava no clipboard.

Um exemplo, supondo que você tenha um sistema de richtext (`contentEditable` ou `designMode`), o qual permite em web editar o HTML como se fosse o microsoftword ou programa semelhante, você poderia prevenir do usuário inserir no HTML coisas indevidas, fazendo a limpeza do conteúdo do clipboard obtido, deixando somente as tags permitidas.

Outro exemplo seria no evento `copy` para checar se o valor atual do clipboard já atende-se a uma necessidade e impedisse de copiar outro, então para checar o valor atual teria que usar o `getData` também, isso claro dependendo da necessidade de quem esta desenvolvendo a aplicação.

O uso e vantagem do `getData` vai da necessidade do ambiente e do que de fato você precisa, um método ou função não precisa ser criada com um propósito tão especifico, o propósito básico do `getData` é isto, obter o clipboard, o que você vai fazer com ele após isto é de intenção e necessidade exclusivamente sua, por isso tantas APIs (não só de clipboard) permitem *"manipuladores"* (handlers), para que o desenvolvedor customize a ação conforme uma necessidade pessoal.

---

Um detalhe importante é apesar de hoje os método ser funcional em praticamente todos navegadores, ele não era algo comum, exceto no IE, isso só foi mudado com o tempo, e como a implementação foi baseada no IE para os demais é provável este o motivo de estar sinalizado como experimental em algumas documentações.